# How to recover deleted projects and organizations in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In case a project and organization got deleted by mistake, How to recover deleted project and organization in Azure DevOps?

[image]

Comment: Is it Azure DevOps Server (on-premise) or Azure DevOps Services (cloud) you use? If it is Azure DevOps Services, and if the project is not there, I assume you have deleting over 28 days. IF that is not the case, you might need to contact Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project or organization is deleted within 28 days, you can recover it in a few steps.

For organization, I advise you to check Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/recover-your-organization?view=azure-devops).

For projects, it is very simple, regarding Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/restore-project?view=azure-devops).

1. Click on Organization settings
   [image]
2. Click overview and there is a category called Recently deleted projects with a list of projects that you can recover.
   [image]

Enjoy.

Comment: Hi Maytham, I have not found recover projects section in my case. PFA screenshot in my first thread.